# $(a,b)$ with $a, b \gt 0$ on $f(x)=4-x^2$ so that the area of the triangle limited by X- , Y-axis, tangent on $f(x$) at $(a,b)$ is minimal?

Tags: calculus, geometry, analysis

How can I determine the point $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ with $a, b \gt 0$ on $f(x)=4-x^2$ so that the area of the triangle which is limited by the X- and Y-axis and by the tangent on $f(x$) at $(a,b)$ is minimal?

The area of the triangle is $(ycoordinate(intersection_{tangent, y-axis})*xcoordinate(intersection_{tanget,x-axis}))$/2

If we derive $f(x)$ we get $f'(x)=-2x$. Because $y=kx+d$ we get $d=f(a)+2xa = 4+x^2$ so $y(intersection_{tangent, y-axis})$ should be $4+a^2$.

But somehow I cant get any further

[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7kbO.png)

[original task(in german!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxuth.png)

Comment: Can you made a Image from this Problem?

Comment: added a sketch. Looking for the coordinates of (a,b) so that the area between x-axis, y-axis and the tangent is minimal

Comment: is it only one Tangent or two?

Comment: One tangent. The tangent is touching $f$ at $f(a)$.

Comment: As I think you speak german, I uploaded a picture of the original task (in german)

Comment: that is nice, i think also i understand the Problem now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $$y=mx+n$$ the searched Tangent line at the Point $$P(a;f(a))$$ then the slope is given by $$f'(x)=-2x$$ and in $a$ $$f'(a)=-2a$$ so our Tangent line has the equation
$$y=-2ax+n$$ since $$f(a)=4-a^2$$ we get
$$y=-2ax+4+a^2$$ now the $y$ intercept is $$4+a^2$$ and the $x$ intercept $$x=\frac{4+a^2}{2a}$$ therefore our tringle has the area:
$$A=\frac{1}{2}(4+a^2)\left(\frac{4+a^2}{2a}\right)$$Can you finish now?
we get $$A_{min}=\frac{32}{3\sqrt{3}}$$ for $$a=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$$